# Flash Messages are not working express/nodejs/ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, flash-message

Flash messages seem to not be working and I think I am missing something super obvious, but I've been at it an hour, and I still have no idea on why it is not working.

My Middleware:

```
// Session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'stuffedbagels',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Express Messages middleware
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
```

App route, just for testing purposes.

```
// Route that creates a flash message using the express-flash module
app.all('/express-flash', function( req, res ) {
    req.flash('success', 'This is a flash message using the express-flash module.');
    res.redirect(301, '/');
});
```

Template (copied right from their github)

```
<div id="messages">
<% Object.keys(messages).forEach(function (type) { %>
  <ul class="<%= type %>">
  <% messages[type].forEach(function (message) { %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% }) %>
  </ul>
<% }) %>
</div>
```

How I'm rendering it

```
<%- messages('msg_temp', locals) %>
```

Now I'm not sure what's wrong, and I've tried every possible fix I found on here, and through google, but it just doesn't seem to to want to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set message with a key like error/success

```
req.flash('success', "hello flash");
```

and you'll get same key in your res.locals or can say while rendering on view like

```
            {% if success %}
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                 {{ success }}
            </div>
{% endif %}
```

**NOTE:** 
flash store key in session cookie,  message flushed only once

Comment: That's what that 'success' is for isn't it? and what the template is for. I've seen this exact setup work, which is why I'm confused it is not working for me.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but this doesn't work anyways. ejs itself thorws a syntax error.

Comment: @William i think it's not so hard try to debug error. good luck

Comment: Doing it with correct syntax doesn't work either, so :/. the only thing that has produced results is `<%- messages('msg_temp', locals) %>`

Comment: no success is not doing anything, @shivshankar you are wrong the res.locals.messages is responsible for storing the messages