# Problem logging in with passport getting a TypeError: req.flash

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ejs

I'm having a practically identical problem to this other stack overflow [thread](http://https:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785543/flash-messages-are-not-working-express-nodejs-ejs) however none of the solutions given seems to work.

Here is the error message I get when trying to login:

```
TypeError: req.flash is not a function
at index.js:151:5
```

Here are the important bits from the routes **index.js** file

```
 router.get("/login", function(req, res) {
   res.render("login", {message: req.flash('error')});
 });

 // login Process
  router.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate('local', {
       successRedirect:'customer/dashboard',
       failureRedirect:'/login',
       failureFlash: true
     })(req, res, next);
   }); 
    **// this where im getting an error**
    module.exports = router;
```

So the error is pointing towards router.post which calls the LocalStrategy in my **passport.js** file:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
  //LocalStrategy
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(email, password, done) {
      let query = {email: email};
      // checking the name in the database against the one submitted on the form
      Customer.findOne(query, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!customer) {
          return done(null, false, { message : 'No such password', type : 'error' });
        }
        //Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, customer.password, function(err, isMatch) {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, customer);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message : 'No such password', type : 'error' });
            // if the password isnt an matc return wrong password
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );
}
  passport.serializeUser(function(customer, done) {
    done(null, customer.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Customer.findById(id, function(err, customer) {
      done(err, customer);
    });
  });
```

and my **login.ejs** file has the code stated in the documentation:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

I've thripled checked everything including the configuration of the dependencies in my app.js file:

```
// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);
// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cookieparser());

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('server is running');
});
app.use(flash());
app.use(routes);
```

Please help! I've spent around 11 hours on this one bug.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `passport.authenticate`, you're passing `res` twice:

```
 passport.authenticate('local', {
   successRedirect:'customer/dashboard',
   failureRedirect:'/login',
   failureFlash: true
 })(res, res, next);
    ^^^  ^^^
```

That first one should be `req`, obviously.

Apart from that though, I don't see `req` being defined anywhere in `passport.js`. If you need to access `req` inside the strategy handler, you need to set the `passReqToCallback` option:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback : true }, function(req, email, password, done) {
  ...
}));
```

Also, when calling `done`, you need to use a fixed format for the third argument:

```
{ message : 'No such password', type : 'error' }
```

And when rendering:

```
res.render("login",{ message: req.flash('error') });
```

Comment: Thank you! The error message has stopped showing up but it does not displaying any flash message when I enter incorrect email/password

Comment: @Connor thinking about it, I don't think you need to call `req.flash()` inside the strategy handler at all. Look here: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#verify-callback

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it as follows (null, false, {signupMessage: 'No such password'}); but again it's still not displaying the flash error message :(

Comment: Where are you setting `message`?

Comment: On the login router  res.render("login",{message: req.flash('signupMessage')});

Comment: See edit. You can't use `signupMessage`, there's a fixed format that you need to use.

Comment: Cheers, I've edited it in my original post but not working, however, I been so focused on getting this error message to display that I've just realised that the login doesn't work when entering correct details... So I've messed up even more then I thought but I don't think it should affect the error messages displaying?

Comment: Probably not, no. It's been a while since I used Passport with flash messages, so it may not be entirely correct what I'm posting. Try finding some examples for either Passport or `connect-flash`.